# Summation of the products of the elements of subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, induction

The problem devised by Ginger Bolton and published in the January 1989 issue of College Mathematics Journal (vol. 20, no. 1, p. 68).

Given a positive integer $n \ge 2$, let $S$ be the set of all nonempty subsets of $\{2,3,...,n\}$. For each $S_i\in S$, let $P_i$ be the product of the elements of $S_i$.

Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{2^{n-1}-1} P_i = \frac{(n+1)!}{2}-1$

I'll show my attempt to prove it which I'm not sure is correct, the question is in the end.

I was trying to prove that with mathematical induction, with the property

$Q(n): \sum_{i=1}^{2^{n-1}-1} P_i = \frac{(n+1)!}{2}-1$.

It holds for the base case $n = 2$.

Now I need to prove $Q(k) \rightarrow Q(k+1)$, that is to show that

$\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}-1} P_i = \frac{(k+2)!}{2}-1$

To prove that, I observe that the subsets of $\{2,3,...,k,k+1\}$ either contain $k+1$ or not. Those that don't contain $k+1$ are subsets of $\{2,3,...,k\}$, for which the inductive hypothesis holds.

Now for each subset $X$ that doesn't contain $k+1$ there is a counterpart $X \cup \{k+1\} \subseteq \{2,3,...,k,k+1\}$. Also note that the number of subsets that don't have $k+1$ and those that have it is equal.

Let $s_{k+1}$ be the sum of products of the elements of subsets of a set with cardinality $k+1$. Then

$s_{k+1} = s_k + (k+1)s_k + (k+1)$

The right part of this equation is:

*the sum for the subsets without* $(k+1)$ +  *the sum for the subsets with* $(k+1)$ + $\emptyset \cup (k+1)$.

Substituting the right part of the inductive hypothesis into the equation I get

$s_{k+1} = s_k + (k+1)s_k + k = \bigl( \frac{(k+1)!}{2}-1 \bigr) + (k+1)\bigl( \frac{(k+1)!}{2}-1 \bigr) + (k+1)$ = *(some algebra)* = $\frac{(k+2)!}{2}-1$

Thus I have made a conjecture of what the sum for a set of cardinality $k+1$ must be and shown that it indeed equals to the right part of the equation from the conclusion of the inductive step.

But what about the conclusion's left part? Do I need to show that $s_{k+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}-1} P_i$ to complete the proof?

Comment: I don't get your question. I think $s_k$ is by definition equal to $\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k-1} - 1} P_i$ for all $k$. So your inductive step is completely valid and finished. PS : there is a nice trick to  show directly the result. If $P = (X+2)(X+3) \cdots (X+k)$, then $s_k = P(1) - 1$ by expanding $P$.

Comment: I've probably overthought it and confused myself.

Answer (score 1):

For any $A$, we have
$$\sum_{\substack{S \subseteq A:\\S \not= \emptyset\\}} \prod_{j \in S} j=\prod_{j \in A} (1+j) - 1.$$
In particular, $A=\{2,\dots,n\}$ yields
$$\sum_{\substack{S \subseteq \{2,\dots,n\}:\\S \not= \emptyset\\}} \prod_{j \in S} j=\prod_{j \in \{2,\dots,n\}} (1+j) - 1=\frac{1}{2}\prod_{j =1}^n\ (1+j)-1=\frac{(n+1)!}{2}-1.$$